# webkit browsers displacing button

Tags: css, webkit

So I have a 36px tall div with a form (`#refine_search`) in it.  The form only contains a 35px tall button (`#refine_search_button`).  All is well until I add a span after the form with a font-size over 17px.  At that point the button will be displayed 2 or 3 pixels down from the top of the div.

[image]

You can see it in action here: 
http://nolasatellitegovernment.tulane.edu/search.php

CSS:

```
 #bluenav {
    width:1124px;
    height:36px;
    position:relative;
    background:url(/g/internal_page_blue_nav_bg.jpg) repeat-x #afdeff;
 }

  #refine_search {
      display:inline;
      padding:0 0 0 110px;  
      margin:0;
    }

    #refine_search_button {
      width:92px;
      height:35px;
      background:url(/g/refine_search_button.jpg) no-repeat;
      border:0;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
    }

    #refine_search_button:hover {
      background:url(/g/refine_search_button_over.jpg) no-repeat;
    }

    .big_heading {
      font-size:22px;
      font-weight:bold;
    }
```

And the code looks like

```
<div id="bluenav"><form action="refine_search.php" id="refine_search"><input type="submit" id="refine_search_button" name="submit" value="" /></form><span style="padding:0 10px 0 20px; font-size:22px">
</div>
```

Does anyone know why 18px text would displace the preceding button in a 35px tall container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#refine_search {
  display:block;
  float: left;
  padding:0 0 0 110px;  
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `vertical-align: top` to `#refine_search_button`.

The default `vertical-align` value is `baseline`, and adding the `span` with different `font-size` adjusts where the baseline is.

If you would also like to vertically center the "Index Results" text, add `line-height: 36px` to the containing `span`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `line-height:36px` to your #refine_search_button id and that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use display:inline they are dependent on each other, like images and text on the same line. Instead try using display:block; float:left; on both elements, then they will always float to the top :)

It might even work with display:inline-block;

IMO its better do generel better coding than using line-height etc to fix a dynamic problem (ie. you change font-size and so on)